# isPalindrome Function C++ Issues

Tags: c++

I am writing a program with a function that tests a word to see if it is a palindrome. The compiler does not complain and the program rums but no matter what word is entered. Can someone tell me why this is? I even copied the isPalindrome function from the book I'm using. I do not know what semantic problem is occurring.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome (string str);

int main()
{
    string word;

    string str;

    cout << "Enter a word to test if it is a palindrome. \n";
    cin >> str;

    for (int i=0; word [i] != '\0'; i++)
            { word[i] = tolower (word[i]); }

    isPalindrome(word);

    if (isPalindrome(word) == 1)
        cout << "The word you entered is a palindrome." << endl;
    if (isPalindrome(word) == 0)
        cout << "The word you entered is not a palindrome." << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(string str)
{
    int length = str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++)
        if (str[i] != str[length - 1 - i])
            return false;

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to step through the code and see how the variables are being modified?

Comment: Can you finish this sentence: "and the program rums but no matter what word is entered." ? Does it stagger? always report not a palindrome?

Comment: word is not initialized. Also, c++ strings are not null terminated.

Comment: Use a debugger and single step through the code.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is an excellent time.

Comment: You don't really need to call the function three times to determine whether the word is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two string variables, "word" and "str." Your input gets stored in "str," but you call isPalindrome with "word"